# is it possible to run a ceph rbd on erasure coded ceph pool, without a separate replicated metadata pool?

Tags: ceph

I'm new to ceph so forgive me if this is common knowledge, but I can't find it. This seems like a simple question, but I can't find any solid answer. In 2017 when rbd on ec pools was first implemented, you had to have a separate replicated pool to store the rbd metadata and then you could store the actual data on the ec pool.

Is this still true or is there nowadays some way to store the metadata in the same ec_pool so I don't have to manage two pools to make an rbd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quincy [docs](https://docs.ceph.com/en/quincy/rados/operations/erasure-code/#erasure-coding-with-overwrites) (current stable release) still state what you already noted:

> Erasure-coded pools do not support omap, so to use them with RBD and
> CephFS you must instruct them to store their data in an EC pool and
> their metadata in a replicated pool.